# Javafx components should always be in center of AnchorPane

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I want my Javafx Components like Labels, TextFields wrapped in VBoxes separately, to be remain in the center of the window even if it's resized. see attatched Images. Currently these components are contained in an anchorPane. 
FXML file code is given below. Please provide me an idea how to do this. Thanks.

[Image for small size window where components are in middle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhVJt.png)

[Full sized window but component position is not changed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rokQ9.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="650.0" minWidth="850.0" prefHeight="650.0" prefWidth="850.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<children>
  <HBox layoutY="-1.0" minWidth="500.0" prefHeight="653.0" prefWidth="850.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
     <children>
        <MenuBar layoutY="-1.0" minWidth="500.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="850.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
          <menus>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Account">
              <items>
                <MenuItem fx:id="menuItemCreate" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Create" />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="menuItemUpdate" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Update" />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="menuItemDelete" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="menuItemLedger" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Ledger" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="In Stock">
              <items>
                <MenuItem fx:id="menuItemAddItem" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add items" />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="menuItemInventory" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Inventory" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Reports">
              <items>
                <MenuItem fx:id="menuItemSalesReport" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Sales report" />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="menuItemProfitReport" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Profit report" />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="menuItemRcvables" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Receivables" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
          </menus>
        </MenuBar>
     </children>
  </HBox>
  <AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPaneUpdate" layoutY="30.0" prefHeight="620.0" prefWidth="850.0" visible="false">
     <children>
        <VBox layoutX="300.0" layoutY="150.0" prefHeight="120.0" prefWidth="60.0" spacing="30.0">
           <children>
              <Label alignment="BASELINE_RIGHT" prefWidth="60.0" text="Full Name" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
              <Label alignment="BASELINE_RIGHT" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Address" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
              <Label alignment="BASELINE_RIGHT" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="27.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="CNIC" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
              <Label alignment="BASELINE_RIGHT" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="44.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Mobile #" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
           </children>
        </VBox>
        <VBox layoutX="400.0" layoutY="150.0" spacing="20.0">
           <children>
              <TextField layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" promptText="Full name" />
              <TextField promptText="Full name" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
              <TextField promptText="Current address" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
              <TextField promptText="XXXXX-XXXXXXX-X" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
              <TextField promptText="XXXX-XXXXXXX" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="70.0" text="Create" />
           </children>
        </VBox>
        <Label layoutX="50.0" layoutY="80.0" text="Update a customer account">
           <font>
              <Font name="Arial Narrow Bold" size="17.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
     </children></AnchorPane>
  <AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPaneDelete" layoutY="30.0" prefHeight="620.0" prefWidth="850.0" visible="false" />
  <AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPaneLedger" layoutY="30.0" prefHeight="620.0" prefWidth="850.0" visible="false" />
  <AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPaneAddItem" layoutY="30.0" prefHeight="620.0" prefWidth="850.0" visible="false" />
  <AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPaneInventory" layoutY="30.0" prefHeight="620.0" prefWidth="850.0" visible="false" />
  <AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPaneSalesReport" layoutY="30.0" prefHeight="620.0" prefWidth="850.0" visible="false" />
  <AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPaneProfitReport" layoutY="30.0" prefHeight="620.0" prefWidth="850.0" visible="false" />
  <AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPanerRcvable" layoutY="30.0" prefHeight="620.0" prefWidth="850.0" visible="false" />
  <VBox layoutX="300.0" layoutY="230.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="199.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="300.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="301.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="200.0">
     <children>
        <StackPane fx:id="pane_main" minHeight="200.0" minWidth="200.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
           <children>
              <Group>
                 <children>
                    <VBox spacing="10.0">
                       <children>
                          <HBox prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="330.0" spacing="30.0">
                             <children>
                                <Label alignment="BASELINE_RIGHT" prefWidth="80.0" text="Search Name" />
                                <TextField minWidth="130.0" prefWidth="130.0" promptText="Enter name" />
                             </children>
                          </HBox>
                          <Label alignment="BASELINE_RIGHT" prefWidth="80.0" text="Details:" />
                          <Separator minWidth="165.0" prefHeight="10.0" prefWidth="330.0" />
                          <HBox spacing="30.0">
                             <children>
                                <VBox spacing="30.0">
                                   <children>
                                      <Label alignment="BASELINE_RIGHT" prefWidth="80.0" text="Full Name" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
                                      <Label alignment="BASELINE_RIGHT" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Address" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
                                      <Label alignment="BASELINE_RIGHT" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="CNIC" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
                                      <Label alignment="BASELINE_RIGHT" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="20.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Mobile #" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
                                   </children>
                                </VBox>
                                <VBox layoutX="100.0" spacing="20.0">
                                   <children>
                                      <TextField minWidth="130.0" prefWidth="130.0" promptText="Full name" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
                                      <TextField minWidth="130.0" prefWidth="130.0" promptText="Current address" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
                                      <TextField minWidth="130.0" prefWidth="130.0" promptText="XXXXX-XXXXXXX-X" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
                                      <TextField minWidth="130.0" prefWidth="130.0" promptText="XXXX-XXXXXXX" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
                                      <Button minWidth="70.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="70.0" text="Create" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
                                   </children>
                                </VBox>
                             </children>
                          </HBox>
                          <Label text="Update a customer account" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
                             <font>
                                <Font name="Arial Narrow Bold" size="17.0" />
                             </font>
                          </Label>
                       </children>
                    </VBox>
                 </children>
              </Group>
           </children>
        </StackPane>
     </children>
  </VBox>
  </children>
  </AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should put all the things that you like to stay in the middle inside a Group. Then you put your Group inside StackPane. This way your Group always stays at the center of the StackPane. Define the StackPane's sizes as you wish, or just bind it to the AnchorPane parent, as in the example:

It should become something like this in fxml:

```
    <AnchorPane>
       <children>
          <StackPane AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.left...>
             <children>
                <Group StackPane.alignment="CENTER">
                   <children>
                      ...       
                    </children>
                 </Group>
              </children>
            </StackPane>
          </children>
     </AnchorPane>
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, i did so, it worked. But as i have a number of anchorPanes for each menuItem. As i put stackPane into sub anchorPane it didn't work. can you please help for this. Thanks;

Comment: Just changed in FXML file. please check it and let me know how i can restrict the window to be resized the size of components at minimum. @aviv-dinitz

Comment: I looked at it, seems that it always stays at the center at resizing. So I don't really understand where do you want to put it. If you ant to put the StackPane in couple different places, you can just create a new fxml with the StackPane and add it to each one of the AnchorPanes.

Comment: but how can i restrict the window size to the size of components while it shrinks. ??

Answer (score 0):

I quickly put this together. In your code are many AnchorPanes and the elements for the form in the middle are in different positions, which I think makes everything harder. Instead, I used a GridPane:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <MenuBar>
            <menus>
                <Menu text="Account">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem fx:id="menuItemCreate" text="Create" />
                        <MenuItem fx:id="menuItemUpdate" text="Update" />
                        <MenuItem fx:id="menuItemDelete" text="Delete" />
                        <MenuItem fx:id="menuItemLedger" text="Ledger" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu text="In Stock">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem fx:id="menuItemAddItem" text="Add items" />
                        <MenuItem fx:id="menuItemInventory" text="Inventory" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu text="Reports">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem fx:id="menuItemSalesReport" text="Sales report" />
                        <MenuItem fx:id="menuItemProfitReport" text="Profit report" />
                        <MenuItem fx:id="menuItemRcvables" text="Receivables" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
            </menus>
        </MenuBar>
        <BorderPane VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
            <top>
                <Label text="Create a new customer account" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                    <font>
                        <Font name="Arial Narrow Bold" size="17.0" />
                    </font>
                    <BorderPane.margin>
                        <Insets />
                    </BorderPane.margin>
                </Label>
            </top>
            <center>
                <GridPane alignment="TOP_CENTER" hgap="10.0" vgap="5.0">
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" percentWidth="0.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" percentWidth="0.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints />
                        <RowConstraints />
                        <RowConstraints />
                        <RowConstraints />
                    </rowConstraints>
                    <children>
                        <Label text="Label">
                            <GridPane.margin>
                                <Insets />
                            </GridPane.margin>
                        </Label>
                        <Label text="Label" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <Label text="Label" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                        <Label text="Label" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                        <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                        <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                        <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                    </children>
                    <BorderPane.margin>
                        <Insets top="15.0" />
                    </BorderPane.margin>
                </GridPane>
            </center>
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets top="15.0" />
            </VBox.margin>
        </BorderPane>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

If you want it to re-size with the top and/or bottom, you could adjust the margin.

**Note**: As I see in your code, there are plenty of invisible objects. I do not know if they are there on purpose or just dead code. In my example, I only created the stuff that is visible.

Comment: Yes there are many invisible objects, as currently didn't use them. will add some functionality later. And each anchorPane is for is menuItem. well let me try this one. Thanks for your help :)